# How to display php echo the same as you see in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a MySQL table called _post and i have a column called message (TEXT)

When i insert a row into the table the text looks like this in phpmyadmin

**This is Correct How I Want It To Display**

```
How much do you use your computer?
You might be spending to much time.....
```

But when i echo it out of the database it looks like this

```
    How much do you use your computer? You might be spending to much time.....
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use something like nl2br() function.

Comment: That's the name of the function :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to convert `\n` (newlines) to `<br>`s.

Answer (score 0):

Since your output is processed as HTML you won't see the newlines that are present in your database. In HTML you need a `<br>`-tag to display a newline in your browser.

PHP has a function that converts any newline to a `<br>`-tag for you: [nl2br()](http://php.net/nl2br)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nl2br() function to display your data.

Example:

```
echo nl2br($mysql_text);
```

Regards